# tapping is not working on Webview for Windows metro style apps

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm not able to get the OnTapped event whenever the user clicks on Webview in windows 8 metro style apps after the webview is navigatedtoString.

using: 
Windows 8 Release Preview
Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

That is because WebView is not a typical XAML control. Hence, It doesn't support any Pointer/Gesture related events.