# Gesture event for webview in Windows store

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am working in windows Store project using c#. My intention is to load local HTML file 
in webview. I did Html file to display Horizebtally with using of Invoking Javascript to webview.

Right now I am getting struggle about read the HTML page Slide by Slide using Gesture like(swipe, Tap).

I didn't see any event like `View Changed` or any other property to get gesture from Webview. I know webview is quite different from Remaining XAML controls to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426120/tapping-is-not-working-on-webview-for-windows-metro-style-apps)

Some people using webview in Flipview, Webviewbrush with webview

But I am wondering about Which solution is suitable for to retrieve event from Webview.

Can any one give me Suggestion about this

Comment: If your html page does not contain any links or any click events the You better go for webview Brush ... else rendering in webview will do ... Only thing is you wont get the xaml events like tap , swipe etc on the webview .

Comment: Yes. The HTML contains links.
It may look like this. [http://www.nextofwindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/BookReader.png ]

As U said **Rendering webview** means which concept you are telling about.
Can you please elaborate your suggestion.

Comment: See web view is a control that is rendered on top of xaml .... so considering what your requirement is like ... multiple html pages and multiple web views the (since web view will have link no use of web view brush) in a flip view the swipe event of the flip view will also not function properly ... try designing it in a way that you get to change the pages of flip view using the arrows ...

Comment: Please clear me this point

Some people using webview in Flipview, Webviewbrush with webview


---------------------------------------------------------- 

In case you want events from web view you need to use script notify .

Comment: @Anobik I saw in the forums for this kind of situation we can use Flipview & webviewbrush(I am not clear which one is suitable).

As your second Comment says the Change pages of Flipview using the Arrows. Ok I will try to use the Flipview & get back to you.

Comment: Do get back to me on the situation .... I am Myself not clear .... and always remember WebView will always be on top of other controls .... so expect very little of the web view to behave as a xaml control